# Shutdown for X time / USB device stop

Tags: usb, shutdown

Is there a way to shut Windows down for 5 min remotely?
I have a conference room where the camera stops working and the onsite tech needs to go unplug the USB to resume operation.

Just curious if I can get it fixed remotely.
Shutdown /r isn't good enough... I either need to somehow stop the USB port or shut down windows for a min or so.

Comment: Can you remote into the machine?  That is normally simple to do. You can shut down or restart remotely. Also determine why the camera stops working - not alt all normal.

Comment: I agree.
But the camera stops working on all 500 of my rooms.
I have mircosoft and logiteh engineers and no one can tell me why.
every time the camera has to be powered down.

And yes, I remote into them all the time, as is my job. However, running a shutdown /r will not cut the USB power for long enough for the camera to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this device, https://www.yepkit.com/product/300115/YKUSHXS which can be switched on/off using a command line tool. Effectively acts as unplugging and pluging back in the USB device.